# Issue with clickable buttons in JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to create a JTable which has clickable buttons in one column. I have been following a tutorial found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LiSHPqbuic. Essentially, when you click one of the buttons a message box pops up. My code almost works but I have to double click the buttons rather than single click. I have been playing around with it for quite sometime and not made much progress. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

package buttoncolumn;

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class ButtonColumn extends JFrame {

    public ButtonColumn() {
        super("Button Column Example");

    //Data for table
    Object[][] data=
    {
        {"1","Man Utd",new Integer(2013),"21"},
        {"2","Man City",new Integer(2014),"3"},
        {"3","Chelsea",new Integer(2015),"7"},
        {"4","Arsenal",new Integer(1999),"10"},
        {"5","Liverpool",new Integer(1990),"19"},
        {"6","Everton",new Integer(1974),"1"},
    };


    //Column header
    String columnHeaders[]={"Position","Team","Last Year Won","Trophies"};
        //Create table object
    JTable table=new JTable(data,columnHeaders);

    //Set custom renderer to teams column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());;

    //Set custom editor to team column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField()));

    //Scroll pane
    JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(pane);
    setSize(450,100);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonColumn bc = new ButtonColumn();
        bc.setVisible(true);
    }

}

//Button renderer class
class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer
{
    //Constructir
    public ButtonRenderer(){
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
            boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {

            setText((obj==null) ? "":obj.toString());

        return this;
    }

}

//Button editor class

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    protected JButton btn;
    private String lbl;
    private Boolean clicked;

    public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt){
        super(txt);

        btn=new JButton();
        btn.setOpaque(true);

        //When button is clicked
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){             

                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
    }
    //Overide a couple of methods
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean selected, int row, int col) {        

        //Set button text
        lbl=(obj==null) ? "":obj.toString();
        btn.setText(lbl);     
        clicked=true; 
        return btn;
    }
    //If button cell value changes (clicked)
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue(){

        if(clicked)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, lbl+" Clicked");
        }
        clicked = false;
      return new String(lbl);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing(){

       clicked=false;
       return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireEditingStopped(){
        super.fireEditingStopped();
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you consult the documentation for more information about the classes you are creating.

Have a look at the [JavaDocs for `DefaultCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) for more details.

Essentially, you need to modify the `isCellEditable` method of the `DefaultCellEditor`

```
class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    //...

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return anEvent instanceof MouseEvent && ((MouseEvent) anEvent).getClickCount() == 1 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton((MouseEvent) anEvent);
    }

}
```

Or, if you really want it simple, just use [`setClickCountToStart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#setClickCountToStart-int-)

```
class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    //...
    public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt) {
        super(txt);

        setClickCountToStart(1);
        //...
    }

}
```